# What is the difference between SYSTEM_USER and USER in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am very new to databases and confused between the keywords [SYSTEM_USER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx) and [USER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186738.aspx) in MSSQL. The definitions say that they return the username in the current context. but the instance I have running returns 'dbo' for USER and 'sa' for system user.

Can somebody highlight the exact difference between the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `SYSTEM_USER`: returns Server Login name that was used to login to the instance (either SQL Server login or AD/Domain/Windows user-name).
- `USER`, `CURRENT_USER`, `USER_NAME()`, or `SESSION_USER`: these all return **Database User principal**, which is (by default) ***dbo*** if you are db-owner or logged in as a *sysadmin* or *sa* (not to be confused with the *dbo* schema or the *DB_Owner* of current database in use).

**Examples:**

```
SELECT SYSTEM_USER      --> myDomain\user.name
----------------------------------------------
SELECT USER             --> dbo
SELECT CURRENT_USER     --> dbo 
SELECT USER_NAME()      --> dbo
SELECT SESSION_USER     --> dbo
----------------------------------------------
```

Note: `USER_NAME([user_id])` can additionally take an int-user-id, default arg is 1, i.e.: `USER_NAME(1)` would be same as `USER_NAME()`.

Answer (score 1):

SYSTEM_USER to return the current system user name.

USER to return the database user name.

Answer (score 0):

According to [difference between SYSTEM_USER and USER](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/143548-difference-between-system_user-user#post537087):

> If the current user is logged in to Microsoft® SQL ServerT using
>   Windows Authentication, SYSTEM_USER returns the Windows 2000 or
>   Windows NT 4.0 login identification name
>
> for example, DOMAIN\user_login_name.
>
> However, if the current user is logged in to SQL Server using SQL
>   Server Authentication, SYSTEM_USER returns the SQL Server login
>   identification name,
>
> for example, sa for a user logged in as sa